# I cannot access the my library when running my VodaPay Mini-Program web-view app from a browser

Tags: webview, vodapay-miniprogram

I am busy developing a mini-program using VodaPay mini-programs and rendering my web-page in an H5 web-view.

I have imported the CDN and it works correctly in the Simulator and while running on device on the VodaPay super-app. But when running on device I get the following error:

```
my is not defined
```

How do I prevent this from occurring? And why does this issue occur?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appx/web-view.min.js"></script>
<script>

  // Sends message to VodaPay Mini-Program.
  my.postMessage({name:"test web-view"});

  // Did receive message from VodaPay Mini-Program.
  my.onMessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e); // {'sendToWebView': '1'}
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Web-View cdn will only run when your mini-app is running on device or in the Simulator. Therefore it is necessary to first check if the my. library is available in order to establish that it's running in a Mini-Program context.

```
<!-- MINI: Used to communicate with mini app. Have to include the script body here otherwise we get my. not recognized errors <START>-->
<script src="https://appx/web-view.min.js"></script>
<script id="messageSend">
    function sendMessage(data) {
        //If not in mini app webview then my. throws errors
        try {
            my.postMessage(data);
        } catch(error) {
        //Prevent my. from throwing error in browser
        }
    }
</script>

<script id="messageReceive">
    try {
        //Store message in session storage, and then change messageReceiveListener innerText to trigger a mutation event to notify that a message has arrived.
        my.onMessage = function (e) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('message',JSON.stringify(e)); 
            document.getElementById('messageReceiveListener').innerText = e; 
        }
        sessionStorage.setItem('inMiniProgram',true);
    } catch(error){          //Prevent my. from throwing error in browser          
            sessionStorage.setItem('inMiniProgram',false);        
    }      
</script>
<input id="messageReceiveListener" hidden></input>
 <!-- MINI:<END> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty with wrapping all calls in try-catch is that you could be masking other errors too.  What I'm doing instead is to check if the useragent contains "alipayclient" and render the html/js content conditionally, which also reduces the amount of html/js rendered for all other non-Vodapay users of the website.